# Making a table structure without using the <table> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do is something like this:

[image]

That's one row of a `<table>`. In other words, it's a `<tr>` which contains three `<td>`s. Now I want to make the same structure without using `<table>` tag *(also without using `<ul> <li>` tag)*.

I want to do that by using `<div>`s. Is it possible?

This is my code:

---

```html
<div class="share_edit_flag">
  <span>share</span>
  <span>share</span>
  <span>share</span>
</div>

<div class="editor">
  <a href="#">edited May 21 16 at 11:58</a>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="#" />
    <a href="#">Rory O'Kane</a>
    <b>12.6k</b>
    <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="author">
  <a href="#">asked May 21 16 at 11:51</a>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="#" />
    <a href="#">vasanthkumarmani</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see, the result of my code doesn't look like the image which is in the top of my question.

As far as I know, I need to set `float`, `display` properties to them. I've tested them, but without achieving the expected result.

Comment: post your css please, and yes floating elements is one way

Comment: Perhaps have a look at some tutorials on how to get your [`div`s to act like `table`s](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di)

Comment: checkout [this](https://html-cleaner.com/features/replace-html-table-tags-with-divs/) example.

Comment: You should take a look at Bootstrap, a great standard for handling layouts like this: http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `display:table` and `display:table-cell` properties.

> **table** - Let the element behave like a `<table>` element
>
> **table-cell** - Let the element behave like a `<td>` element

Since you only need one row, you can skip the `table-row` (`<tr>`) element if you want. More info about the [display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) here.

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) is also a good solution, unless you want support for older browsers and IE.

Example:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%; //if you want the table to extend the full width of the parent
}

.table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red; //added this for highlight
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="share_edit_flag">
    <span>share</span>
    <span>share</span>
    <span>share</span>
  </div>

  <div class="editor">
    <a href="#">edited May 21 16 at 11:58</a>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="#" />
      <a href="#">Rory O'Kane</a>
      <b>12.6k</b>
      <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="author">
    <a href="#">asked May 21 16 at 11:51</a>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="#" />
      <a href="#">vasanthkumarmani</a>
      <b>1</b>
      <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `editor` box should be center ..! I guess you have to set `width:100%;` to the table

Comment: It is centered. Inspect the element.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px; }

.first {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: red; }

.second {
  width: 100px;
  background: green; }

.third {
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

You can achieved it using flexbox. And it is also flexible in container with 100% width. However, old browsers is not supported.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible indeed.

Not too long ago, [css flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) was released and is now usable, prefixed, in the majority of browsers. This is used very often on the web and is a very good skill to learn.

Lately [css grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) crept up. Not worth spending too much time on, in my opinion, but it's a nice skill to have nevertheless